# Get data from custom search form and display results in a page (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue to display results from a search form in a page.

I have in my header.php a custom search form :

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('/pagesearch/')?>" method="get" id="adminbarsearch">
    <input type="search" id="place"  name="mydata" />
    <input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Rechercher"/>*/?>
</form>
```

When a user submits the form, I retrieve the data and modify it, through this code in my functions.php :

```
if ((isset($_GET['mydata'])) && (!empty($_GET['mydata']))){
    $q = sanitize_text_field($_GET['mydata']);      
    $search_posts_id = array();

    $search_args = array(
            's' => $q,
            'fields' => array('ids', 'post_type'),
            'post_type' => 'my_custom_posttype'
    );
    $search_query = new WP_Query($search_args);

    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) :
            $search_posts_id = array_unique(wp_list_pluck( $search_query->posts, 'post_title', 'id' ));
            $search_posts_id = implode( ',', $search_posts_id );
    else :
            $search_posts_id = implode( ',', $search_posts_id );
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 

    echo $search_posts_id;
```

The problem is that I would like to display the result which is `$search_posts_id` in the "pagesearch" page of my website.

When I use the code above, it displays in the page but before the header and everything, and not in the content, between the header and the footer.

I don't know how to put this data correctly in the content.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're echoing from your functions.php file -- this runs before the theme's header and content render, so it's going to just output before everything else.

You'll need to take a different approach, like potentially placing this code inside page.php (or whatever template you want it in) possibly before the the_content() call, or maybe even creating a custom shortcode to display this content wherever you want.

If you can provide some more info on where specifically you'd like these results to show up, we might be able to assist further. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I had tried that before and it didn't work, and I have tried again and it works perfect. I should have done a mistake the first time.